# Deploy GWT Application to Google App Engine using NetBeans

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, netbeans

I try to deploy a GWT application, to Google App Engine using NetBeans.

I had successful run GWT sample http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/create.html using Personal GlassFish v3 Prelude Domain, by

1) Copy generated source code from StockWatcher to C:\Projects\StockWatcherNetbeans\src\java\com\google\

2) Modify C:\Projects\StockWatcherNetbeans\nbproject\gwt.properties

> ```
> gwt.module=com.google.gwt.stockwatcher.StockWatcher
> ```

3) Select Personal GlassFish v3 Prelude Domain, and run.

---

All works fine!

Now, I try to select Google App Engine server, and run. However, I get the error

> "There is no appengine web project
>   opened!"

I check... There is file called

> C:\Projects\StockWatcherNetbeans\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml

with content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0"
xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
xsi:schemaLocation='http://kenai.com/projects/nbappengine/downloads/download/schema/appengine-web.xsd appengine-web.xsd'>
    <application>StockWatcherNetbeans</application>
    <version>1</version>
</appengine-web-app>
```

I am using

1. NetBeans 6.7.1
2. GWT4NB (GWT Plugin for NetBeans) 2.6.12
3. Google App Engine plugin for NetBeans from http://kenai.com/downloads/nbappengine/1.0_NetBeans671/updates.xml

Anything I had missed out?

Even when I right click to the project, the **Deploy to Google App Engine** options is disabled.

And yes, please do not ask me why not use Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Starting with GWT 1.6, static files
>   have been moved to /war.

Instead of using war folder, I rename it to web folder. The Google App Engine plug-in comes with NetBeans needs the files to be placed in web folder.